# How to Discretize this SDE found in finance?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, eulers-method

#### Continuous-Time

In continuous-time form, the ["Heston model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model) is written as

$$
dS_t = \mu S_t \,dt + \sqrt{\nu_t} S_t \, dW_t^S \\
d\nu_t = \kappa (\theta - \nu_t)\, dt + \xi \sqrt{v_t} \, dW_t^\nu
$$

where $W_t^\nu$ and $W_t^S$ are Wiener processes with correlation $\rho$, $\mu$, $\theta$, $\kappa$, $\xi$ and $\rho$ are parameters, $S_t$ is the observable stock price process, and $\nu_t$ is the unobserved variance process.

##### Discrete-Time

The discrete-time version of this is usually my starting point:

$$
y_t = \varepsilon_t \exp(h_t / 2) \\
h_{t+1} = \mu(1 - \phi) + \phi h_t + \sigma_\eta \eta_t
$$
where $\{\eta_t\}$ and $\{\varepsilon_t\}$ are correlated ($\rho$) mean zero unit variance normal variates, $y_t$ is the stock *return* ending at time $t$, and $h_t$ is the logarithm of the return's variance. $\mu$, $\phi$, $\sigma_\eta$, and $\rho$ are the parameters of the model.

##### Question

**How is the former discretized into the latter?**

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845825/discretizing-a-stochastic-volatility-sde), but it was for a simpler model. In the reference mentioned in that answer, it mentions that it's pretty typical to use one of four schemes that discretize a process. You use Euler schemes on each stated process separately, perhaps applying Ito's lemma to find the log diffusion, first. I've tried them, but they don't come out looking the same. Perhaps there is some approximation argument applied in the finance literature I don't know about?

Comment: Your discrete time model should not be a discretization of Heston. It's a well-known stochastic volatility model in discrete time. Heston schemes for simulations have been hugely studied.

Comment: @Snoop I think you’re right. I’m misreading a footnote maybe. I can get the variance to be homoskedastic if I use a square root transform, but it doesn’t discretize in the way that I suspected. Unless there’s some out-there approximate approximation strategy, I don’t think this will work.

Comment: Maybe more suited for this forum : https://quant.stackexchange.com/